# Help comprehending the work required to drain a hemispherical tank with radius 5

Tags: calculus, integration

Q: Suppose a hemispherical has a radius of 5 and is full of water calculate the total work required to drain the entire hemisphere.

For this problem, I am not sure if I fully understand how to set up the distance for each slice of water and the limits of integration. I did this two different ways and not sure if either are correct.

Picture of method 1 and 2:

[image]

What I did was take a horizontal slice of the hemisphere creating a cylindrical disk, and then calculate the volume of that.

$V_{slice} = π·r^{2}·h$

$V_{slice} = π·r^{2}·dy$

Now I need to find a generic radius, the radius is given for the hemisphere but not for when it is changing. So to solve this I created a triangle.
'y' is the opposite, 'r' is our adjacent unknown, and r = 5 is the hypotenuse.
Then I got:

$r =\sqrt{25 - y^{2}}$

So,

$V_{slice} = π·(25 - y^{2})·dy$

So for the first one I got the limits of integration ranging from -5 to 0 and distance just being y, because we only consider the positive end of the spectrum and since it's under the x-axis we just consider positive y.

So that's:

$W = \displaystyle\int_{-5}^{0} (62.5)·π·(25 - y^{2})·(y)·dy$

For the second one, I did the same but then the limits of integration and distance would change. Distance will now be on the positive end of the spectrum above the x-axis so it's 5 - y.
So that's:

$W = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{5} (62.5)·π·(25 - y^{2})·(5 - y)·dy$

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first the limits of integration say $y$ is increasing upward.  The distance you lift the water is $-y$, which will change the sign of the integral to positive.  For the second the radius is zero at $y=0$ so your term $25-y^2$ should be $25-(5-y)^2$

Comment: Aren't both increasing upwards? The first is increasing upwards from -5 to 0 and second is increasing upwards from o to 5? Why would the distance be - y? I am so confused.

Comment: Yes, they are both increasing upwards.  In the first the water starts out with a $y$ coordinate less than zero, so the distance it is lifted is $-y$.  The water that starts out at $y=-2$ must be lifted by $2$ to get to $0$ and get out of the tank.

Comment: Isn't the technique to find distance for a slice, initial minus final, so initial for the first is = 0, and final be - 5, so -5 - y. And for the second wouldn't the initial be = 5 and final be = 0. so 5 - 0, therefore 5 -  y? Thank you

Comment: Or is it, for the first initial = -5 to final = 0. And for the second initial = 0 to final = 5 ?

Comment: No, the distance is from where the slice starts to where it finishes.  In the first the finish is at $0$ because that is how high it needs to be to get out of the tank.  It starts at $y$ so the lift is $0-y$.  In the second it needs to be lifted to $5$ so the lift is $5-y$

Comment: Thank you, Is there an algorithm to get this for these problems. I heard there was something like initial minus final to get the distance. But it doesn't seem to be working. Because for the first that would be initial = -5, final = 0. So - 5 - 0 = - 5. Don't understand how that would become 0 - y. And for the second initial = 0 and final = 5. So  0 - 5 = - 5 again, how does this become 5 - y. Sorry, this is tough for me to understand.

Comment: I think I get the algorithm. Is it just BIG minus SMALL? where small is just put in as the 'y' variable? So in the first one BIG is 0 and SMALL is a -5, so we put that as BIG minus small or 0 for BIG and minus small - y, where 'y' will be evaluated later on by the integral?

Comment: It is the ending height for each bit of water minus the starting height.  In this problem all the water ends at the rim of the container so the ending height is $0$ on the left and $5$ on the right.  In another problem it could be different.  If you were filling a tub from the bottom the starting height would be zero and the ending height would vary depending on the final location of the water.

Comment: So for the first the distance isn't (y)? even though it's on the x-axis?

Comment: Oh yeah, if it's BIG minus SMALL I need to still include the negative!

Comment: And the second is just (5 - y)

Comment: I think for these spheres it's best to center the at the origin.

Comment: I think referring to it as BIG and SMALL is a mistake, which is why I used beginning and ending.  You could have a problem where you empty the tank under gravity and energy is released.  That will change the sign.  You can put the zero anywhere you want as long as you are consistent.

Comment: In the  problems I have had, no energy and gravity were part of the problem, this is for calculus 2. The questions are phrased just like one I gave. Should I be okay with this method?

Comment: The work is energy.  You should really have a factor $\rho g$ for the density of the water multiplied by gravity to change the lifted volume into energy.  The drain out problems would end with the water lower than it started, releasing energy instead of absorbing it.  They are done the same way.

Comment: The way my teacher set it up was like, sorry on my phone. Integral a to b *(62.5)*(volume of slice)*(distance)*dy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58362/discussion-between-yre-and-ross-millikan).

Comment: That's 62.5 lbs/ft^3 for water density. Other that this aspect would the rest of the method be correct with the distance being (-4) and the rest of what I have 0